# Spark adding extra space when record contain a "comma"

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My input is a "|" (pipe) separator file. I can't change the input file. 
The format is

```
HEADER_A|HEADER_B|HEADER_C
A|B|C
A D|B|  => records without comma generates output like "A D|B|"
A,D|B|  => records with comma generates output like    " A,D|B| "
```

Spark config is :

```
sparkSession.read()
 .option("header","true")
 .option("delimiter","|")
 .schema(schema) * assume this is valid and represents the correct schema
 .csv(fileName)
.cache();
```

I've tried using the "sep" option but didn't work as well.
If my delimiter is "|", why Spark has a different effect on records with a comma?

Comment: Could you modify the input file in a way where you do not actually modify it but the program takes it in with the characters changed? This appears to be a bug and that may fix it.

Comment: Can't reproduce it using your input text. How do you get your output? A file or console display?

Comment: File. writing as: dataset.write().option("emptyValue","").option("nullValue","").csv(file_path);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error. As the record contains a comma, I should not use the .csv(path) when writing the file
Changing from

```
dataset.write()...
.csv(path)
```

to

```
dataset,write()...
.text(path)
```

solved it